# How to back second activity to first activity if no internet connection/wifi/mobile data (JAVA_CODE)

Tags: java, android-studio

I am beginner android developer... Recently I develop an apps. But I want If user device connected with wifi/mobile network and user open my apps automatically FirstActivity go to SecondActivity. In SecondActivity user can read a pdfBook/html/txt file. But when user Reading Pdfbook/html/txt file in SecondActivity and at the same time wifi/mobile network DISCONNECTED then SecondActivity automatically should come_back to FirstActivity. I try many way, but I fail to do that.... there is no resource in GoogleSearch for this problem. Please anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }
```

this is the function that will return true if the network is connected

and return false if the network is not connected

if this function return true you go to next activty

if return false then what you want can do